# Viewing all possible Application property values

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-shell

Where is the best place to look at to find an exhaustive list of Spring Application.properties list?

I have looked everywhere but I was unable to find a complete list of possible Spring application.properties list.

This link: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html only provides some of the common ones but I'm interested in properties that are used inside the Spring Shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the [provided link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html) shows *all common* spring boot application properties...

But every [Spring Project](https://spring.io/projects) somewhat cooks his own.. :)

The best "documentation" at the moment (at least it is a complete overview) is currently/unfortunately the source code of:

[`SpringShellProperties`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-shell/blob/main/spring-shell-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/shell/boot/SpringShellProperties.java), which are the (typesafe, `prefix="spring.shell"`) "configuration properties" for spring-shell-starter.

Only few of them are (currently) mentioned in the [(3.0.3) reference doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-shell/docs/3.0.3/docs/).